# Cast DbSet<T> and call method

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, reflection

I am trying to write a method that casts a property to DbSet and than calls the load method.

I have tried the following:

```
var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(em, null) as DbSet;
//Not working, because it always returns null

var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(em, null) as DbSet<T>;
//Not working, because its a syntax error and doesnt even compile (giving error 'Cannot resolve symbol T')

var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(em, null) as DbSet<TEntity>;
//Not working, because its a syntax error and doesnt even compile (giving error 'Cannot resolve symbol TEntity')
```

But only when I specify the correct type its working:

```
var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(em, null) as DbSet<TempTable>;
```

How can I solve this with out specifying TempTable?

Comment: "But only when I specify the correct type its working:" - well, can you tell us exactly what happens when it isn't working? what is the error / exception / etc? Also: what is `T` and `TEntity` here? is it the same as `TempTable`, but as a generic type parameter?

Comment: @MarcGravell: have a look at my edit, I just puted T or TEntity there is hope, thats the way of doing it, also tried with <object> but this also returns a null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(em, null) as DbSet;
//Not working, because it always returns null
```

Indeed; `DbSet<TEntity>` does not inherit from `DbSet`, so yes, that will always be `null`.

```
//Not working, because its a syntax error and doesnt even compile (giving error 'Cannot resolve symbol T')
```

You need to know the type of something to talk to it; you could use the non-generic `IEnumerable` / `IQueryable` APIs, but I suspect the most appropriate evil here might be `dynamic`:

```
dynamic val = propertyInfo.GetValue(em, null);
EvilMethod(val);

//...

void EvilMethod<T>(DbSet<T> data)
{
    // this will resolve, and you now know the `T` you are talking about as `T`
    data.Load();
}
```

or if you **just** want to call `Load`:

```
dynamic val = propertyInfo.GetValue(em, null);
val.Load();
```

Comment: I have tried it with dynamic in the first place, but when I do so I am getting the exception that Load() isnt a method of DbSet<TempTable>, which propably is because its just a static extension that doesnt apply to dynamic, maybe a bug in C#?

Comment: The method EvildMethod is working, but calling the .Load() direclty as in your last example doesnt work. With the error message, from my previous post. (DbSet<TempTable> does not contain definition of Load())

Comment: @Rand yes, that is because it is an extension method - something I didn't know; because of that, I strongly suggest you use Reda's approach unless you actually need it as a `DbSet<T>`

Comment: I would need both the .Load method and the .Local property, to load and work with the list, so for now the only thing working 100% is the EvilMethod though it sounds evil is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(em, null) as IQueryable;
value.Load();
```

Comment: It's an extension method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.load(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps:

```
var setMethod = typeof(MyDataContext)
    .GetMethods(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .Where(m => m.Name == "Set")
    .Where(m => m.IsGenericMethod)
    .Select(m => m.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TEntity)))
    .SingleOrDefault();

var value = setMethod.Invoke(myDataContextInstance, null);
```